# Calculating trait disparity between sister species

Tags: r, phylogeny

I have a phylogeny and 3-D morphometric data. I want to calculate trait disparity between sister taxa PC scores. Is there a function in R or R script that will do this?

Comment: The [dispRity](https://rawgit.com/TGuillerme/dispRity/master/inst/gitbook/_book/index.html) R package might be useful. Unfortunately this question is likely to be closed, as it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use the [dispRity](https://github.com/TGuillerme/dispRity) package as suggested in the comments in combination with the [geomorph](https://github.com/geomorphR/geomorph) package.

Once your 3D data is properly read into `R` via `geomorph` you can use this simple pipeline:

```
## Make sure the packages are installed
library(dispRity)
library(geomorph)

## Some example 2D dataset
data(plethodon)

## Performing some GPA
procrustes <- gpagen(plethodon$land, PrinAxes=FALSE)

## Creating a geomorph dataframe
geomorphDF <- geomorph.data.frame(procrustes, species = plethodon$species)

## Creating a dispRity object and performing and ordination
ordination <- geomorph.ordination(geomorphDF)

## Measuring disparity as the sum of variances
disparity <- dispRity(ordination, metric = c(sum, variances))

summary(disparity)
#         subsets  n   obs
# 1  species.Jord 20 0.004
# 2 species.Teyah 20 0.004
```

Of course, I strongly suggest the implications and decisions that you have to make at each step (detailed information for each steps can be found in the functions manuals).

Comment: This approach does not take phylogeny into account.

Comment: Correct, this only measures trait disparity within groups (as asked in your question) and does not test any hypothesis. I you want to test some hypotheses, there exist many ways and some do indeed take into account phylogenetic history. An recent overview of some of these methods is available [here](https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/67/1/14/3867043) (pay walled unfortunately).